# How to add classname type to the parameter of abstract method?

Tags: php, html, oop, polymorphism, extends

I have an abstract class with this method:

```
abstract class X {
   abstract public function method( $param );
}
```

In the implementation I do:

```
class Y extends X {
   public function method( ClassName1 $param )
   {
       ...
   }
}

class W extends X {
   public function method( ClassName2 $param )
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

I need to put the `ClassName1` and the `ClassName2` in both methods, but I get this error:

Declaration of `Y::method()` must be compatible with `X::method($param)` in ...

What I need to declare the abstract method in class X to solve the problem?
The real question maybe: What be the class name in `X::method( _____ $param )` to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an interface. `ClassName1` and `ClassName2` implement that interface. Now you can use your interface as a type-hint in your method parameter. Based on your tag `polymorphism`, you may know how to use interfaces, what they are and what the benefits are. This approach is called ***Design by contract*** and is considered best practice.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to get away with doing this because you're type hinting two different classes. When you use an `abstract` or `interface`, it's basically a promise to implement a method in the same way the it's been previously defined. Your adding of the type hint makes them decidedly incompatible.

The best thing I can suggest is to do the check inside the method itself

```
class Y extends X {
   public function method( $param )
   {
       if(get_class($param) != 'ClassName1') throw new Exception('Expected class ClassName1');
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, in Java we can create the X class like this: `public abstract class X<T> {   public abstract void method( T param ); } public abstract class Y<ClassName1> {   public void method( ClassName1 param )   {     ...    }}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the unique way to go is this?

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

abstract class X {
      public abstract function method( A $param );
}

class Y {
      public function method(B $param ) {}
}


class Z {
      public function method(C $param ) {}
}

$y = new Y();
$z = new Z();

?>
```